# Pipe input command line to bash interpreter

Tags: bash, go

I'm writing a small program with an interpreter, I would like to pipe any command that is not recognized by my shell to bash, and print the output as if written in a normal terminal.

```
func RunExtern(c *shell.Cmd) (string, os.Error) {   
    cmd := exec.Command(c.Cmd(), c.Args()...)
    out, err := cmd.Output()

    return string(out), err
}
```

this is what I've written so far, but it only executes a program with its args, I would like to send the whole line to bash and get the output, any idea how to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, to list directory entries in columns,

```
package main

import (
    "exec"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func BashExec(argv []string) (string, os.Error) {
    cmdarg := ""
    for _, arg := range argv {
        cmdarg += `"` + arg + `" `
    }
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmdarg)
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    return string(out), err
}

func main() {
    out, err := BashExec([]string{`ls`, `-C`})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

Comment: the -c !!

I tried running bash only, should've manned it.
Thank's a lot :)